# ion-content overlaps with ion-header

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic5

Following is my configuration.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.6.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.0.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/kishorpawar/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v12.12.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.11.3
   OS                : macOS Catalina
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.4.1 Build version 11E503a
```

[this doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content) says the following.

[image].

But still, my `ion-content` overlaps with `ion-header`

I am trying [this usage example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll#usage) with `ion-virtual-scroll`. I tried `fullscreen`, `padding`, `has_header` and other solutions on the forum including old ionic versions.

I have the following code in my `app.component.html`.

```
<ion-app>
    <ion-header [translucent]="true">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title size="medium">
          <ion-img [src]="header_logo" height="150" width='150'></ion-img>
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
<ion-app>
```

and the `ion-content` is present in every component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question on [ionic-forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-content-overlaps-with-ion-header/187607), and `Mike Hartington` from ionic-team replied with the following.

> Hey there! So this isn’t actually how you should be structuring your
>   DOM.
>
> ion-header is not meant to be a “global” component in this case. It
>   should be included in all your pages. This is probably why you’re
>   having issues.

So basically, I had to move `ion-header` from `app.component.html` to every page I will be building.